# mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')

Tags: python, c++

I want to use C++ functions in Python program, so I compiled the dynamic library file with the command:

```
cc -fPIC -shared -o encrypt_for_python.so encrypt_for_python.cpp -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1l/lib -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1l/include -lssl -lcrypto -std=c++11
```

But when I used it in python file, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/debris/Documents/Job/HA/encryption-cpp/test_encrypt.py", line 6, in <module>
    my_func = CDLL(so_file)
  File "/Users/debris/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 382, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/Users/debris/Documents/Job/HA/encryption-cpp/encrypt_for_python.so, 0x0006): tried: '/Users/debris/Documents/Job/HA/encryption-cpp/encrypt_for_python.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/local/lib/encrypt_for_python.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/encrypt_for_python.so' (no such file)
```

I found **mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')**, how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm guessing you have an x86_64 installation of python, either install an arm version or compile your c++ code for x86_64

Comment: Yes, I found this:
/Users/debris/miniconda3/bin/python: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

But my computer's architecture is arm64, how can I get python for arm64?

Comment: https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/ ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have solved this problem through installing python for amd64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this:

```
file ~/miniconda3/bin/python
/Users/debris/miniconda3/bin/python: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

By installing python for amd64, I solved this problem.@Alan Birtles Thank you very much.