# Is there any way to get cffi to install both x86_64 and arm64 mach-o files on a Macbook(M1)?

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, pip, cffi

I am really pulling my hair out onf this one.
I upgraded python from 3.9 to 3.11 on my Macbook (M1 Max chip) yesterday and reinstalled all the packages via pip.
Everything seemed to work well, until I wanted to run my program that uses the module netmiko.

In the mac terminal and in iterm2, everything worked as expected.  However, if I try to use the terminal in VSCode, I get the following error message:

> ImportError:
> dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried:
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need
> 'x86_64'))

I don't understand why VSCode needs to use an x86_64 mach-o file when it is on a Mac.

I tried to fix the problem by reinstalling cffi, argon2-cffi and netmiko.
The funny thing is that if I reinstall cffi from within VSCode, cffi will create the necessary x86_64 mach-o but will not install the arm64 version needed for the mac terminal as seen here:

> ImportError:
> dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried:
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need
> 'arm64e' or 'arm64'))

So the problem lies either with pip or cffi, since they refuse to create both versions.  Is there a way to get cffi to create both mach-o versions on my Macbook?

Thanks

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71247107/mach-o-file-but-is-an-incompatible-architecture-have-arm64-need-x86-64) solve your issue?

Comment: As I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77979177/cffi-package-broken-in-mac-m2-arm-chip-but-is-an-incompatible-architecture-h/78097593#78097593), I ran into a similar issue. I created Mach-O universal binary, which would solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall cffi:

```
pip uninstall cffi
```

Then install cffi from source for arm64

```
arch -arm64 pip install --no-cache cffi --no-binary :all:
```